# Await asynchronous command in unit test

Tags: c#, task

I use async commands based on
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx

An executor of the command looks like this:

```
(package) =>
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        dataProvider.Save(package);
        // emulate long running operation
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; ++i)
        {
            string[] ar = new string[1000];
        }
}).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    messagingService.Send(new PackageSavedMessage
    {
        Id = package.Id,
        Name = package.Name,
    });
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

It works well when I click on save button in the application, i.e. it asynchronously waits, then *ContinueWith* fires.

But when I try to call it from unit test

```
[Test]
public async Task SaveCommand_Test()
{
    using (var scope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var vm = scope.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
        AsyncCommandBase acb = vm.PackageViewModels[0].SaveCommand as AsyncCommandBase;
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
        await acb.ExecuteAsync(package);
    }
}
```

*ContinueWith* fires immediately, not waiting for task finished

If I don't set SynchronizationContext, I get an error

> The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler.

Comment: Why do you manually set the synchronization context? Also, if you want unit test async stuff, I suggest passing down the schedulers via `IScheduler`, so that you can replace them

Comment: How do you know it does not wait? Creating 5 million objects should take a fraction of a second. It might just appear to be instant. Set breakpoints to find out.

Comment: @krzysztof-skowronek you mean to create a service which would provide me with context? (Btw, the topic issue is resolved - I go exception, actually waiting works)

Comment: No, just inject it in constructor, if null use defaults as always

Comment: @krzysztof-skowronek do you have an example?

Comment: for example in Rx oeprator like `Delay` you can wrtite `obs.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSecond(1), DispatcherScheduler.Current)` to move execution to dispatcher after the delay. While this is not constructor, but still uses DI

Comment: @amplifier: I believe `usr` is correct: the `ContinueWith` is probably working just fine. That said, strongly consider using `await` instead of `ContinueWith`.

Comment: @stephen-cleary Hi Stephen! now it works, it appeared that I had unhanded exception. Yes, _await_ is a very cool thing but in my case I want to have a Func<Task> that does something long-running and after that it updates the UI. I want to pass that Func<Task> into an AsyncCommand, that's why I use ContinueWith.


_p.s. your book is great!_

Comment: @amplifier: `await` should work just fine for that; it captures and restores UI context by default.

Comment: @stephen-cleary do you mean to replace 
_return Task.Run(()=>{do1()}).ContinueWith(){do2();}_ with 
_public async Task Executor(){await Task.Run(()=>{do1();}); do2();}_

Comment: @amplifier: Yes, that's the gist of it.

Comment: @stephen-cleary Thank you, I would consider it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your executor shouldn't need to use `ContinueWith`; a more modern `await` would work just as well (note that [`await` will automatically capture and resume its context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), so no explicit `TaskScheduler` is necessary):

```
async (package) =>
{
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    dataProvider.Save(package);
    // emulate long running operation
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; ++i)
    {
      string[] ar = new string[1000];
    }
  });
  messagingService.Send(new PackageSavedMessage
  {
    Id = package.Id,
    Name = package.Name,
  });
}
```